# Optmizing functions

Tags: c++, function, factorial

There is a section of the book I am using to learn c++ which teaches about optimizing functions.

The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int computeFactorials(int, int);

int factorial(int);

int main() {
    computeFactorials(1, 5);
    return 0;
}

int computeFactorials(int num, int max) {
    cout << "Factorial of " << num << ": ";
    cout << factorial(num) << endl;
    num++;
    if(num > max)
        return 0;
    else
        computeFactorials(num, max);
}

int factorial(int n) {
    int result;
    if (n == 1)
         result = 1;
    else
         result = (factorial(n-1) * n);
    return result;
}
```

Here is the program execution:

```
Factorial of 10: 3628800

C:\MyPrograms\c++ optimize.cpp -o optimize.exe

C:\MyPrograms>optimize
Factorial of 1: 1
Factorial of 2: 2
Factorial of 3: 6
Factorial of 4: 24
Factorial of 5: 120
```

I can follow up to num == 3, but when it gets to 4 my logic doesn't add up with the results.  I am reading the code like this:

`computeFactorials(1,5)`, 1 meaning the number to start at, and 5 meaning the maximum number of loops. I'm going to start at 3 per se because I understand 1 and 2 as num.

"Factorial of " (3) : `factorial(3)`, then in the factorial function 3 is subtracted by 1 equaling 2, and then multiplied by 3 for a result of 6.

However, when the program gets to num equaling 4 this doesn't seem to make any sense anymore.  Because the int result of the factorials() functions should equal 12 not 24.

```
else result = (factorials (4-1) * 4) ;
```

3 * 4 = 12, not 24. How is this program getting to 24 and not 12? Then once again doing the same thing on num = 5, getting 120 rather than 20.

Please help me understand, I am still very nooby in this language, thank you. :)

Comment: To understand recursion, you first have to understand recursion ;-)

Comment: @Roger The first rule about recursion is that you do not talk about recursion.

Comment: @remyabel aaaaargh - I messed up my termination condition ... sorry(sorry(sorry(sorry)))

Comment: The text in them is not illegible, if you open the image in a new tab you can see it, your comments are a waste of space, thank you.

Comment: **factorial(3)*4 = factorial(2)*3*4 = factorial(1)*2*3*4 = 1*2*3*4=24**, isn't it?

Comment: I think you have not clear idea about what factorial is: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: Your `computeFactorials` has undefined behavior.  It is not returning a value on all paths.  Why does it have a non-void return type anyway?

Comment: Yes sir, will have to look into that to get past this page, thank you.

Comment: It's recursion, so unrolling n = 4 for example would essentially give you `((((4-1-1-1) * (4-1-1)) * (4-1)) * 4)`. Or `1 * 2 * 3 * 4`.

Comment: While there are no universally agreed upon rules about formatting C++ code, if the book you are reading from is actually formatting code the way you showed it... that's probably going to be agreed upon as *"terrible"*!  I edited your post to something a bit more standard.  Also, try to avoid using images to show textual code or program output if you can...they're really for graphics only.  The windows console has the ability to mark w/the mouse, copy, and paste...click on the icon in the upper left corner and you should be able to see that.

Comment: Thank you Hostile Fork, Giacomo, and splrs and user19.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then in the factorial function 3 is subtracted by 1 equaling 2, and then multiplied by 3 for a result of 6

No.

In the factorial function, 3 "is subtracted by 1" equalling 2, then this 2 is passed to `factorial` in a recursive call:

- `factorial(2) * 3`
- `= factorial(1) * 2 * 3`
- `= 1 * 2 * 3`
- `= 6`

The result of this call is what is multiplied by 3 for a result of 6.

**It's `(factorial(n-1) * n)`, not `((n-1) * n)`.**

---

> However, when the program gets to num equaling 4 this doesn't seem to make any sense anymore, because the int result of the factorials() functions should equal 12 not 24.

If `factorial(3)` is 6, then `factorial(4)` clearly cannot be only 12 because that's only twice 6. It's not grown enough.

- `factorial(3) * 4`
- `= factorial(2) * 3 * 4`
- `= factorial(1) * 2 * 3 * 4`
- `= 1 * 2 * 3 * 4`
- `= 24`

---

> 3 * 4 = 12, not 24

Correct, but that is not 4 factorial. 4 factorial is 1 * 2 * 3 * 4.

I suspect you're sort of half-confusing [factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) with [the fibonacci sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Comment: Thank you once again Lightness, I'm gonna have to focus on clearly understanding factorials before finishing up this segment. :)